# 'as' operator in PHP

Tags: php, operators

In PHP, what does the operator 'as' do? For example,

```
foreach ( $this->Example as $Example )
```

Thanks.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's take an example:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {}
```

This means

> foreach element (of `$array`) defined as
>   `$value`...

In other words this means that the elements of the array will be retrieved inside the loop `as` `$value`.
Notice that you can specify also this syntax:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {}
```

In both ways the vars `$key` and `$value` will exists inside the `foreach` and will correspond to the 'current' element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

On each iteration of the foreach loop, `$Example` is assigned to the current element in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on existing answers. There's more than one use of `as` keyword. Besides the obvious:

```
foreach ($dictionary as $key => $value) {}
```

It's also used to alias imported resources:

```
<?php
namespace foo;
use Full\Class\Path as MyAlias;
new MyAlias();
```

Which is useful, e.g. as a shorthand for `AVeryLongClassNameThatRendersYourCodeUnreadable` or to substitute an object with your implementation when extending third party code.

Answer (score 2):

It's only used with `foreach` and it defines the variable (or key/value variable pair) that represents the current item in the array.

Answer (score 2):

here is info from http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
```

The first form loops over the array given by array_expression.

On each loop, **the value of the current element is assigned to $value** and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next loop, you'll be looking at the next element).

Answer (score 0):

Takes each entries in the array ie, $this->Example and puts it in $Example

more details in http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

It's used in a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct to iterate through an array.  The code in the `foreach` block will be run for each element in the array (in this example, `$this->Example`).  Every time it is run, the variable after `as` (in this example, `$Example`) will be set to the value of the current element in the array.